# Proof Regarding the Intersection of Indexed Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove that for each $\beta\in\Lambda$, $\bigcap ${
$A_\alpha:\alpha\in\Lambda$} $ \subseteq  A_\beta$

I was thinking of converting it to an If-Then statement like,

If $\beta\in\Lambda$, then $\bigcap ${
$A_\alpha:\alpha\in\Lambda$} $ \subseteq  A_\beta$

Comment: If $x$ is in the intersection, then it's in $A_\beta$ for all $\beta\in\Lambda.$ It's just the definition of intersection.

Comment: I was thinking that to. It is just such a simple statement, somewhat obvious. I didn't know if I was missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition the intersection $\bigcap \{A_\alpha : \alpha \in \Lambda\}$ is the set of all elements that are in every $A_\alpha$. In notation:
$$
\bigcap \{A_\alpha : \alpha \in \Lambda\} = \{x : \forall \alpha \in \Lambda(x \in A_\alpha)\}.
$$

Now your statement follows quickly. Let $\beta \in \lambda$ and let $x \in \bigcap \{A_\alpha : \alpha \in \Lambda\}$. Then by definition $x \in A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \Lambda$. So in particular $x \in A_\beta$, and we can indeed conclude $\bigcap \{A_\alpha : \alpha \in \Lambda\} \subseteq A_\beta$.